# Select from multi tables and return all

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

```
posts [post_id post_title post_body post_date post_by post_accepted] 
users [user_id user_name user_pw]
comments [comment_id comment_user comment_co comment_post comment_date]
categories [categorie_id categorie_name]
```

Each table contain a data all data are belong to table posts:

```
categories<-posts
posts<-users
posts<-comments<-users
```

I want to get posts with id post_id and get with it a comments and who post it and get the category name and id.

I tried but I get the post but not all comments or if the post does not have comment it will no appear.

This my SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(comment_id),comments.*,categories.*,users.*,posts.* 
FROM posts
JOIN categories on (posts.post_id = categories.categorie_id)
JOIN users on (posts.post_by = users.user_id)
LEFT JOIN comments on (posts.post_id = comments.comment_post)
WHERE posts.post_id='34' 
AND  posts.post_accepted = '1' ;
```

Comment: You have to use left outer join for comments. Inner join will require there to be rows in the table. Also you will get multiple rows for comments if there are several and count will yield 1. You cannot get multiple rows in one row like this.

Comment: Also do consider the naming of the columns. Post_by is not a good name for pointing to users table, or using a separate category table which just holds one value for each post. Those belong to the same table if there is a 1-1 relation always. If the table is users, the column should be just name, not user_name, since it's obvious what name it is. Same for post_title, post_body etc.

Comment: thanks @SamiKuhmonen i create function to get the comment counts and join them to array

Answer (score 0):

Try add GROUP BY users.id to your query

Comment: why i use users.id i want to get all comments from table comments for post with post_id and if the post don't have comment i want it to return the post without comment